# Can not set attributes in ie

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble getting a script to add an onsubmit attribute to a form in IE. It works fine in Chrome though.

```
document.getElementsByName('form_name').item(0).setAttribute("onsubmit","add_to_form()");
```

It is grabbing the element fine and I can use `getAttribute` to print out pre-existing attributes just fine.

Comment: Which version of ie? http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Does it produce an error, have you tried using the onsubmit property instead of the attribute?

Comment: I don't understand how this can work in chrome, the form will just submit because there is no prevent default or return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document probably puts IE in Quirks Mode, since in Standards Mode, the code seems to work OK.

To make the code work in Quirks Mode too, you can assign to the DOM property `onsubmit` rather than the HTML attribute. These two do not necessarily correspond to each other in old versions and Quirks Mode of IE. In your example, use this instead:

```
document.getElementsByName('form_name').item(0).onsubmit = add_to_form;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite this:

```
function listen(event, elem, func) { // cross-browser event listener
  if (elem.addEventListener) elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  else if (elem.attachEvent) elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func); // IE
}

listen('load', window, function() {
  var form = document.getElementsByName('form_name')[0];
  listen('submit', form, add_to_form);
});
```